# Zapier CLI - In resources how can I mention UPDATE method

Tags: javascript, rest, zapier, zapier-cli

As mentioned in **resource** schema [here](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-schema/build/schema.html#resourceschema), I can only mention **creates**. My question is how to mention an **update** which in turn will call **PUT** method on my REST API. I searched the documentation but didn't find any such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

We don't have anything specific to an update action, but since you're in control of what sort of request(s) you make, it's pretty easy to build one.

Separate from the resource, you can write an `Update X` action (called a "create" in the docs, which I see is a little confusing) which can make whatever request you want.

We've got docs about updates [here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/how-design-successful-actions/#update-actions).

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Ok that is really helpful ... I will try it.